# Reset filesystem on boot failure

Tags: debian, sd-card, overlayfs

There is a single-board computer booting Debian 11 from an SD-card, and the idea is if it ever fails to boot (eg from losing power mid-write), it attempts to boot from a known-good setup (eg read-only partition).

I've tried overlayroot from Armbian, but it requires getting into `overlayroot-chroot` environment before writing, and I would like it to be transparent. I've also found `mount -t overlay`, but not sure how to set it up for the whole filesystem. I also have an idea to do session saving like live distros do (casper?) or snapshots, but I still have no idea how to detect boot failure and switch to booting from 'base' partition. Am I correct that's how OpenWRT works? How it's done there?

Comment: the "losing power mid-write" is **very** rarely a reason for boot failure in this day and age: you will of course lose the unwritten data, but with any of the file systems that you'd format a Linux system partition, you get *journaling*, which ensures that no power loss at any time corrupts the file system (decades-old bugs that have long long been fixed aside). So, unless the power loss happens while you were overwriting some boot-critical software (e.g. the boot loader), you would not end up with an unbootable system. How often do you update your boot loader, or your systemd-init?

Comment: The more common reason for boot failures in consumer single-board computers is failure of the SD card, caused by using a "cheap with few, sequential writes"-optimized flash medium for random write access (flash wears out when being written to. SD cards aren't as equipped to deal with that as are e.g. "proper" SSDs) Your approach to fall back to a read-only partition is hence a great idea! Generally, however, I'll be very honest in saying that if you actually update critical data on an SD Card, you'll want to replace that SD card at regular intervals.And make sure you `fstrim` or use `discard`!

Answer (score 0):

How "failed boot counting & switching to a safe boot environment" is done depends on what your hardware supports and what you actually want to do. Some platforms have special memory for that, for others you'll want to use software using the storage medium.

Assuming your single-board computer is an EFI system, your Linux distro probably (possibly? I don't know debian's boot process on embedded platforms well enough) supports [systemd-boot](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-boot.html), which comes with [automatic boot assessment](https://systemd.io/AUTOMATIC_BOOT_ASSESSMENT/) to do *exactly* what you describe: boot a different system if necessary :)